# How to set up PowerBI with many identically structured datasources for maximum reusability?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

My company has 50 customers, each with their own instance of MySQL (think of it as 1 machine per customer). Most of the time we can expect all the instances to have the same schema. We'd like to do reporting on each customer.

Assuming the schemas are identically structured, does each customer need their own dataset in PowerBI? If so, this seems difficult to maintain as any update to the underlying schema would require updates in 50 datasets.

We'd like to use the embed API for embedding reports, which I understand accepts a parameter for data*sets* but not data*sources*. This would make reusing reports easy but I'm not confident we can have the same reuse with datasets.

Should we consider aggregating our customer data into one source to make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

There is some automation required, but the *strong* guidance is to create a workspace per customer just like you have a separate database per customer.

If you load all the customers into a single Dataset and use RLS, that dataset will be large and perform worse as every customer will have to filter out every other customer's data.  And you have to design and test the row-level security.

> If the ISV application has a separate database for each customer,
> create single-tenant datasets in Power BI. Provide each dataset with
> connection details that point to its matching database. Use one of the
> following methods to avoid creating multiple identical reports with
> different connection details:
>
> Dataset parameters: Create a dataset with parameters in the connection
> details (such as SQL server name, SQL database name). Then, import a
> report into a customer's workspace and change the parameters to match
> the customer's database details.
>
> Update Datasource API: Create a .pbix that points to a data source
> with sample content. Then, import the .pbix into a customer's
> workspace and change the connection details using the Update
> Datasource API.

[A separate database for each customer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-multi-tenancy#a-separate-database-for-each-customer)

This is all covered in the [Power BI Dev Camp](https://www.powerbidevcamp.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If they are identical you could consolidate into one single data model and apply Row Level Security in your embed solution, which filters data based on group membership.

I would read up on the security features for Power BI embedded in the official documentation, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security